# Administrative Limit Exceeded During C# LDAP Search

Tags: c#, exception, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I am trying to do a LDAP Search however I keep getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072024): T
he administrative limit for this request was exceeded.

   at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext
()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

Here is the code: (The error is thrown at FindOne())

```
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myldap.com:1701/ou=People,o=My Company,c=CA", "", "", AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
        DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);

        string filter = "mail";
        string filterValue = "my.email@mycompany.com";

        dirSearcher.Filter = string.Format("({0}={1})", filter, filterValue);

        SortOption sortOption = new SortOption(filter, SortDirection.Ascending);

        dirSearcher.Sort = sortOption;
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");
        dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        SearchResult result = dirSearcher.FindOne();

        DirectoryEntry directEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", directEntry.Properties["uid"].Value.ToString());
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Is this LDAP against Active Directory, or against some other LDAP directory?? If other: which one??

Comment: The LDAP path just looked a bit odd - I wasn't sure whether AD supports things like `o=` and `c=` - those were typically used in OpenLDAP or Novell eDirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed this line and it works:

```
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");
```

Must have been grabbing the UID from every result instead of just a matching result and therefore was going over the Admin limit.

Comment: According to Richard Mueller's reference site (http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm), Active Directory doesn't seem to contain a "uid" attribute - must be something else you're looking for....

Answer (score 1):

Many LDAP server implementations have limits on how many results will be returned in a query.

AD defaults to 1000 or 2000.  I forget offhand.  eDirectory defaults to no limit. Others vary.

You can either ask the admins to change the limit, or else, page your code so it gets only a page (or limited number of results) at a time.